# Access JSON Array Object jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

Hi I have a ajax request which returns this

```
[[{"totalloginhours":"11.17"}],[{"totalagents":"2"}],[{"totalapplications":"2"}]]
```

How do I access this string in jQuery? I don't need to loop.
I tried using `$.parseJSON` to parse that string

```
var myObj2 = $.parseJSON(result2);
```

which returns

[image]

Comment: `myObj2[0].totalloginhours`?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan myObj2[0].totalloginhours is undefined Sir

Comment: this does the trick `myObj2[0][0]['totalloginhours']`

Answer (score 1):

Foun a way to do this by

```
var string = '[[{"totalloginhours":"11.17"}],[{"totalagents":"2"}],[{"totalapplications":"2"}]]';

var myObj2 = $.parseJSON(string);
var obj_totalloginhours = myObj2[0];
var obj_totalagents = myObj2[1];
var obj_totalapplications= myObj2[2];

console.log(string);
console.log(obj_totalloginhours[0].totalloginhours);
console.log(obj_totalagents[0].totalagents);
console.log(obj_totalapplications[0].totalapplications);
```

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zu0x49ye/